# Using the \tab Command

Tags: spacing

I have seen several cases of people using the `\tab` command to insert a specific amount of space between objects (as opposed to the `\hfill` command which uses any remaining space).  However, I have never been able to get `\tab` to work.  Are there any specific packages or environments that are supposed to accompany `\tab`?

Comment: I am not familiar with `\tab`, but there is a `tabto` package that can come in quite handy.

Comment: I would use `\hspace*{<length>}` -- without the `*` the full space may not be inserted.

Comment: May be `\let\tab\quad`?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

The command `\tab` exists, but it produces quite a large space.  It also requires the use of the package `tabto`.

Alternative options are `\quad` and `\qquad`; the space produced is probably more what you are looking to create.  These commands do not require extra packages and can be stacked (e.g. `Stuff Over Here \quad \quad \quad More Stuff Over Here`) if needed.

You might also want to try using either `$\>$` or `$\-$`.  Neither command requires any extra packages, but both must be in math mode.  Although neither command by itself gives a large space like `\tab` does, the space produced is small.  However, you can stack the commands in order to get the spacing you want.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Manuel You are correct; I could define a term like Herbert wanted.  But that doesn't really solve the problem or answer the question.  The objective is to find a command that will put space between objects and defining a new command doesn't really do that.  Besides, it's bad form to define a new command in each document.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying.  But, as I mentioned previously, the objective is to FIND a command that will put space between objects and defining a new command doesn't really do that. There is no point in creating a command if one already exists, making it unnecessary (what I term "bad form") to define a new command in each document.

Comment: This doesn't align the text as far as I can tell. It just inserts a fixed width space.

Comment: Use \tabto{15mm} to have a tab stop at 15mm (together with package \tabto].

Answer (score 43):

define your own command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\tab[1][1cm]{\hspace*{#1}}
\begin{document}
foo\tab bar\tab[2cm]baz

\tab foo\tab bar\tab[2cm]baz

\rule{1cm}{1pt}foo\rule{1cm}{1pt}bar\rule{2cm}{1pt}baz

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Which is not what \t does. Tab also aligns the text.

Answer (score 16):

If instead of wanting to insert a predetermined amount of spacing within a line, you want to insert variable space that reaches the next predefined tab stop to automatically *align across lines* like a traditional text editor tab, you may use `\NumTabs{⟨number⟩}` and `\tab` from [the `tabto` package](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tabto/tabto-doc.pdf) as so:

```
\NumTabs{8} % define 8 equally spaced tabs starting at the left margin
            % and spanning \linewidth
\begin{itemize}
  \item\textbf{Dolphin}:\tab Delphinidae, Platanistidae, Iniidae, Pontoporiidae
  \item\textbf{Whale}:\tab Balaenopteridae, Balaenidae, Cetotheriidae,
  Eschrichtiidae, Monodontidae, Physeteridae, Kogiidae, Ziphiidae
\end{itemize}
```

Alternatively you may align to any particular length from the left margin with `\tabto{⟨length⟩}` as so:

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item\textbf{Dolphin}:\tabto{5em} Delphinidae, Platanistidae, Iniidae, Pontoporiidae
  \item\textbf{Whale}:\tabto{5em} Balaenopteridae, Balaenidae, Cetotheriidae,
  Eschrichtiidae, Monodontidae, Physeteridae, Kogiidae, Ziphiidae
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Can you put a complete latex code and one screenshot, please?

Comment: This would be what I was looking for... if it worked inside the gather environment.

Comment: This is the  correct answer, `\tab` is not  a horizontal spacer. It is  like press the TAB key in a typewriter or Word , whereas  the equivalent of  `\quad`, `\hpace{10mm}`, \hfill, etc. is like press the SPACE key some (or many) times. Only add, that for a table-like format with unequal columns, is just better define before the default positions with some like `\TabPositions {2cm, 0.25\linewidth, 10 cm, ...}` and then just use `\tab. The \tabto{}` more sense for punctual uses where you do not want change the `\NumTabs` or    `\TabPositions`.

Answer (score 15):

Instead of `\tab`, you may use `\hspace{10mm}` which gives a 10mm space similar to using `\tab`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `tabto` package, as Mathematician suggested.

```
\usepackage{tabto}
\newcommand\mytab{\tabto{1cm}}
```

Yes, the tab command really spaces things a lot.

Answer (score 1):

For me, `\indent` did the trick. Using this does not require any package.

After including a paragraph under `\section{}`, I needed to include another paragraph, but none of the methods mentioned here were working for me to indent the second paragraph. Adding sample code here:

```
\section{Acknowledgment}
The authors would like to thank. . .
\indent The authors would also like to thank. . .
```

Discovered this from [here](https://www.maths.tcd.ie/%7Edwilkins/LaTeXPrimer/WhiteSpace.html)

Comment: You need an empty line before `\indent`, otherwise it would apply to the paragraph above it.

Comment: you can use \\ to avoid the empty line

Comment: @Krauss -- A double backslash should never be used to end a paragraph.  It is suitable for ending a line of poetry or a row in a table or a line line in a multi-line math display.  A paragraph should be ended with a blank line or `\par`.

Answer (score 1):

In the package `tabto`, you can use the command `tabto{1cm}` to create an exact 1cm space in the document. also you can alter the parameter to any number you like.